# How do i generate a certificate to sign pdf electronically?

Tags: libreoffice, pdf, pgp, signature

I'm stuck trying to figure out what kind of certificate I need to create, and how to create it to sign PDF's with LibreOffice. I created a GnuPG key, that did not work. I tried to create a private key (through the 'Passwords and keys' app), but it won't let me.

[image: No buttons to click]

Where am i going wrong here?

I am trying to make a certificate that i can use to electronically sign PDF's.

something that will show up here in libreoffice, when creating documents.

[image]

Thanks a bunch in advance.

Comment: Does this resoource help? https://help.libreoffice.org/Common/Applying_Digital_Signatures

Comment: Yes, that is very helpful. So if i understand correctly, these certificates is nothing you generate, but something you receive from an authority? Funnily Cacert.org's certificate expired the 4th of April, so firefox warns me about it's potential harms.

Comment: It would seem so otherwise how could anyone trust a self generated certificate if it were a "free for all"? I'll précis the resource and add as an answer if you would care to accept it to enable others with a similar question to find it in the future. Many thanks.

Comment: So how does one GET such a certificat on a pristine, just started system?????

Comment: Hi ... perhaps this will help some folk: [Using Okular to Digitally Sign PDFs](https://gregbur.me/2022/04/28/deep-dive-digitally-signing-pdfs-with-okular/).  Looks more promising that the stuff I've seen so far tonight.  Note this quote: ["Digitally signing a PDF is a simple task; however, properly configuring Okular to sign documents can be challenging for new users."](https://gregbur.me/2022/04/28/deep-dive-digitally-signing-pdfs-with-okular/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe it is worth to give some more details, how to sign PDFs with Libreoffice. There are some pitfalls and this is a good place to store the experience I made.

First get yourself a x509 certificate you can use to sign/encrypt emails. Where you can get one, is dynamically changing. The free ones are rare, in worst case create a self signed. There are plenty of explanations in the web on how to do this.
At the end you need a signed certificate including the private key in pk12 format.

For the moment, lets assume the pk12 file is named: `cert.pk12`

```
$ mkdir -p "~/.pki/cert8"
$ certutil -N -d ~/.pki/cert8/
Enter a password which will be used to encrypt your keys.
The password should be at least 8 characters long,
and should contain at least one non-alphabetic character.

Enter new password: 
Re-enter password: 
$ pk12util -d ~/.pki/cert8/ -i cert.pk12
Enter Password or Pin for "NSS Certificate DB":
Enter password for PKCS12 file: 
pk12util: PKCS12 IMPORT SUCCESSFUL
$ ls ~/.pki/cert8/
cert8.db  key3.db  secmod.db
$ certutil -L -d ~/.pki/cert8/

Certificate Nickname                                         Trust Attributes
                                                             SSL,S/MIME,JAR/XPI

xxxx@xxxx.xxx                                                u,u,u
Xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx CA                              ,,   
XXxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx CA                                ,,
```

Now the certificate is in the database.
In Libreoffice in the options (Tools -> Options... -> Security -> Certificate... -> Select NSS path...) the path to the database needs to be configured.

Now the certificate should be selectable in the "Digital Signatures" dialog.

With this at least all tools show me that the PDF is signed. Most of them show me that the signature is valid. But Windows Acrobat Reader still is not convinced. In Acrobat you need to explicitly manually trust the certificate. But my PDFs from Linux are marked as "modified". Maybe the transfer changed the Linux line endings to Windows line endings?

Using "Time Stamp Authotity" (TSA) seems only possible if you go via "Export as PDF".

**Addition:** With `seahorse` (which is started from Libreoffice by clicking on "Start Certificate Manager") it is not possible to add x509 certificates (at least at the time writing this).

Comment: You'll need `libnss3-tools` for `certutil` to work, and you should trail -N after the directory so as to avoid the following error: `certutil: function failed: SEC_ERROR_BAD_DATABASE: security library: bad database.` You can also use `--empty-password` to avoid having a password on the database - and if you don't, the default master firefox password (which is what it's really asking for) is an empty string (just press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Answer (score 3):

Here's how you can generate your own certificate for signing documents within libreoffice on (eg Debian), and get yourself set up to do so:

### Prep

Install necessary tools:

```bash
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install openssl libnss3-tools
```

### Making the certificate

First, [generate an x509 certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41366949/2041005):

```bash
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -sha256 -days 3650 -nodes \
-keyout signing.key -out signing.crt -subj "/CN=John T Doe" \
-addext "subjectAltName=email:you@example.com"

...

..+......+..+....+........+.+.........+...........+.+.....+.+.....+...+.+....
+.....+.+.....+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+++++++++*.........+..+.........+....+.........+...............+......+......
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
-----

...
```

*Note that `subjectAltName` can contain `email:` [instead](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/333325/523016) of DNS entries*

Next, [convert the certificate to a p12 format key](https://help.hcltechsw.com/safelinx/1.2/adminguide/creating_a_self-signed_certificate.html):

```bash
openssl pkcs12 -export -in signing.cert -inkey signing.key \
-out signing-certificate.p12 -name "John T Doe"

...
Enter Export Password:
Verifying - Enter Export Password:
...
```

### Making the NSS Database

Next, we need to [prepare a database path for NSS and generate the database](https://serverfault.com/a/438669):

```bash
mkdir -p ~/.pki/nssdb
certutil -d ~/.pki/nssdb -N

...
Enter Password or Pin for "NSS Certificate DB":
Enter a password which will be used to encrypt your keys.
The password should be at least 8 characters long,
and should contain at least one non-alphabetic character.

Enter new password:
Re-enter password:
Password changed successfully.

...
```

*Note that the password in question is your [default master firefox password (on Debian/Ubuntu)](https://github.com/FiloSottile/mkcert/issues/50#issuecomment-451902544). So if you haven't set one up, its an empty string - once you do it will prompt you to enter a new one and change it*

Or, do so without adding a password (Reference 4):

```bash
certutil -d ~/.pki/nssdb -N --empty-password
```

Finally, [import the p12 certificate into the database](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19159-01/819-3671/ablrh/index.html):

```bash
pk12util -d ~/.pki/nssdb -i signing-certificate.p12

...

Enter Password or Pin for "NSS Certificate DB":
Enter password for PKCS12 file:
pk12util: PKCS12 IMPORT SUCCESSFUL

...
```

*Note that you can use -k ${database.password.file} -w ${certificate.password.file} to flag in the passwords programatically if you want to get fancy*

### Configuring LibreOffice

1. Open LibreOffice
2. Select **Window**
3. Select **Options**
4. Select **Security** on the left
5. On the right, select **Certificate** by *Certificate Path*
6. Select **Select NSS Path** at the bottom of the resulting dialog, select the proper path (i.e. `~/.pki/nssdb`), select **Ok** (ensuring the new Manual path is selected), and finally **Restart Now**.
7. After reboot, open a document, select **File**, select **Export as**, select **Export as PDF**.
8. Navigate to the Digital Signatures tab, and you should see things working:
   [image: NSS Database Password Required]
   [image: Generated & Import Certificate Available to Sign With]
   [image: Certificate Details 1]
   [image: Certificate Details 2]
9. Then select the certificate in question to use it to sign:
   [image: Selected Certificate to Sign with]
10. Enter your certificate password
11. Enter your location and reason (if so desired)
    [image: Add Signature Details]
12. Select **Export** and save your document
    [image: Save signed document]

You can lastly go into **File** ⇨ **Digital Signatures...** ⇨ **Sign Existing PDF**, and open your signed PDF to verify that a signature exists (and you could also sign in this fashion too):

[image: Verify Signed PDF Document 1]
[image: Verify Signed PDF Document 2]

References:

Answer (score 0):

There are three basic stages to obtaining a certificate.

1. You can get a certificate from a certification authority. No matter if you choose a governmental institution or a private company it is common to be charged for this service, for example when they certify your identity. Few other authorities issue certificates free of costs, like the Open Source Project "CAcert" which is based on the well-known and reliable Web of Trust model and is of growing popularity.
2. If you are using Solaris or Linux, you must install a recent version of Thunderbird or Firefox to install some system files that are needed for encryption.
3. Sign the macros inside a document. Normally, macros are part of a document. If you sign a document, the macros inside the document are signed automatically.

[Reference](https://help.libreoffice.org/Common/Applying_Digital_Signatures)

Comment: A small edition for all linux users, thunderbird and firefox use now the new version of the security database (cert9.db, ...), but Libreoffice (tested with version 7.0.4) can only use the old version (cert8.db). Therefore you need to create a new database manually with `certutil` and add your certificate with `pk12util`.